# android, how to format json string with some field bold

Tags: android, json, kotlin, textview

In android `TextView`, when displaying a `json` string, would like to be properly formatted and it should have some specified field bold, like:

{
"location": {
"**country**":"GB",
"weather":[
{
"**zip**":20202,
"description":"sun",
"temp":"80"
}
]
}
},

To be displayed as

[image]

Tried @Zain's solution, seems it does not work (see screenshot below). It is set in a TextView on a Dialog. Indentation is not there.
[image]

update: it is a `TextView` in Dialog:

```
private fun showFormatedJsonString(context: Context, jsonStr: String) {
        val dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.module_path)
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
        dialog.setCancelable(true)
        dialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.json_str).apply {
            
            text = jsonStr
        }
        dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.root_container).setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        
        val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
        val dialogWidth = (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.85).toInt()
        val dialogHeight = (displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.85).toInt()
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight)
        dialog.show()
    }
```

tried with `SpannableStringBuilder`, does not work either

```
//spStrBuilder.color ( Color.CYAN) { append("to be colored") }
                spStrBuilder.bold { append("to be bold") }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple occurrences of the match you'd do this programmatically and use [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) for marking the text with bold

```
String json = "{ \"location\": { \"country\":\"GB\", \"weather\":[ { \"zip\":20202, \"description\":\"sun\", \"temp\":\"80\" } ] } }";
// List of words to be marked with bold
List<String> boldList = Arrays.asList("country", "zip");
final Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(json);

// Finding match of words in the String
for (String word : boldList) {
    int startIndex = json.indexOf(word);
    do {
        int endIndex = startIndex + word.length();
        spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(BOLD), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        startIndex = json.indexOf(word, endIndex);
    } while (startIndex != -1);
}

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.foo);
textView.setText(spannable);
```

**UPDATE**

Using the code in the dialog:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.sometest8)

        val json =
            "{ \"location\": { \"country\":\"GB\", \"weather\":[ { \"zip\":20202, \"description\":\"sun\", \"temp\":\"80\" } ] } }"
        button.setOnClickListener {
            showFormatedJsonString(this, json)
        }
    }


    fun formatBold(json: String): Spannable {
        val boldList: List<String> = listOf("country", "zip")
        val spannable: Spannable = SpannableString(json)

        // Finding match of words in the String
        for (word in boldList) {
            var startIndex = json.indexOf(word)
            do {
                val endIndex = startIndex + word.length
                spannable.setSpan(
                    StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
                    startIndex,
                    endIndex,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
                startIndex = json.indexOf(word, endIndex)
            } while (startIndex != -1)
        }
        return spannable
    }


    private fun showFormatedJsonString(context: Context, jsonStr: String) {
        val dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.module_path)
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
        dialog.setCancelable(true)
        dialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.json_str).apply {
            text = formatBold(jsonStr)
        }
        dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.root_container).setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
        val dialogWidth = (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.85).toInt()
        val dialogHeight = (displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.85).toInt()
        dialog.getWindow()?.setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight)
        dialog.show()
    }

}
```

Preview

[image]

Comment: thanks, but it seems not work. test with the code and update the question with the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry to hear.. But you didn't mention that initially that the textView will be in a dialog... my shareed code is working in normal layouts and tested.. So we need to know how you build up the dialog

Comment: the Dialog is pretty simple, a TextView in it.

Comment: @lannyf Just used your code and the result is the same.. Please have a look at the updated answer

Comment: it does work for you, but not sure why mine is not showing the bold. same code now. will try more. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HtmlCompat.fromHtml( htmlTextHere, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY )` to stylize your text with html tags (In your case `<b>` tag), but this way You must prepare your text like:
`"{\"location\": { <b>\"country\"</b>:"+ object.location.country ...`

Comment: would that take care of the indentation formatting?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried using  `<pre>` tag and different `HtmlCompat` constants but I couldn't stylize it